# Does urls need to constructed dynamically for webfarm?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, deployment, web-farm

We are planning to shift our asp .net mvc application to webfarm with loadbalancer,

I am concern about many hardcoded urls available in the application like.

```
<a href="https://root:xxx/home/index">Index</a>
```

and

**this.RedirectToAction(x=>x.Index());**

and

**Response.Redirect("~/home/index");**

Does this url need to be dynamically constructed inorder to redirect to some specific location, based on RRA algorith.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that should be handled by your load balancer. I would expect the code you've shown to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks Rob, Since there is no environment available tht I can test it but can you provide me some more information about loadbalance works, some web resource may also help, particularly i want be sure about this approach of writing urls.

Comment: First Google result for "how do load balancer work": https://devcentral.f5.com/weblogs/dmacvittie/archive/2009/03/17/intro-to-load-balancing-for-developers-ndash-how-they-work.aspx